# Is it possible to import bulk historical prices from yahoo or google into Excel and calculate 2STD?

Tags: stocks, trading, spreadsheet

I believe a version of this question has been asked before. However, I'm not sure if what I am trying to accomplish can be done. I am trying to import into Excel at the end of each day all of the the S&P 500 stocks and calculate their 2 standard deviation price range gap - either up or down, as defined by their 10 day true range. Too be more accurate, I am looking for excel to calculate their 2std then add back in the 10 day true range mean. This way I can cross reference on the open each day if any of these stocks qualify as breaching this gap. At the moment, I am working with excel and importing one stock at a time. I was hoping that there would be a better and simpler way as this approach is very cumbersome. My ultimate goal would be to import all the opening prices in the morning via Thinkorswim and have excel "find" any stocks that qualify. Anyone know if this can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, free services are explicitly best up to discourage/block bulk downloading. You may need to pay for a service which will let you do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things:
1. Pay for the data and use programming to avoid lots of work, I'm sure there is no shortage of pricedata about S&P 500 companies.
2. Have your own computer save the price every minute. This also involves programming and a program running on your computer all day long.

In general if you are looking to do things like this, programming is really useful. You don't have to be a world-class hacker, but learn a programming language.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I only need end-of-day-data. Not live streaming.Looks like I will have t0 learn VBA to accomplish. Thanks